# Is Microsoft Visual C++ not using the C/C++ calling conventions with floats?

Tags: c++, floating-point, x86, calling-convention

I've been researching floating-point numbers for my compiler projects,
especially how they are converted from decimal notation to bytes. I did find answers to all of my questions, but [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lIA0aPYar8) got me worried.

The guy explains SSE and the instruction set pretty good and I did understand everything, but he also mentions that `Microsoft's Visual C++` apparently does not use the `_stdcall` calling convention when it comes to `floats`. This would be terrible for me as I was planning to use the C calling convention in my own compiler, for calling extern functions as well, of course.

Basic question: Do I have to worry about this, or is it even true?

The main aspect of this is whether Visual C++ also does this when exporting code to a DLL, as this could turn out to be a problem.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Compile a test program with "/Fa".  This will generate assembly output; you'll be able to see *exactly* how MSVC is calling your function.

Comment: @paulsm4 Good idea, though it's mostly about my code calling functions within DLLs that were compiled with Visual C++. I can't try this right now, but I will once I get home.

Comment: MSVC *never* using __stdcall unless explicitly told to do so.  Defaults are __cdecl for C functions and __thiscall for C++ instance methods.  If you want __stdcall on exported functions then you have to declare them that way.

Comment: Visual Studio might not follow conventions for an ordinary function.  But it will most definitely follow conventions for an exported dll function.  I don't think you have to worry.

Comment: Appearantly the [/Gz](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) flag forces functions to be compiled with `_stdcall`

Comment: **The** C/C++ calling convention for floats does not exist.

Comment: @MSalters What do you mean by that? Sorry if this sounds stupid, I am not 100% familiar with all aspects of C++.

Comment: @Kierrow: There are many different calling conventions. Even the `__cdecl` convention mentioned above really is `__cdecl, on x86, Win32`. None of them is official. In other words, neither ISO C nor ISO C++ has an ABI (application binary interface). The question as phrased talks about _the_ calling convention, assuming there's one.

Answer (score 1):

As MSalters indicated in a comment, there is no such thing as "the C/C++ calling conventions".  The calling conventions for both C and C++ depend on the platform (compiler, runtime, OS, and hardware), and are not mentioned anywhere in the C or C++ standards.

It sounds like you want to use `__stdcall`, which has nothing to do with any actual standard as far as I'm aware, despite its name.